# How to define each item for a WPF ListView where the view looks similar to Extra Large Icons view in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, effects

Basically I am trying to do something like [this http://www.crunchgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/popbox.jpg](http://www.crunchgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/popbox.jpg).

Just showing images in a fixed dimension with no text below the images. It also should have a fixed distance between the images horizontally and vertically.

Also if someone could add a mouseover glow effect to simulate the same thing, that would be cool.

I am more familiar with xaml now but I just got confused about defining each item for a `ListView` control. I only used WPF `ListView` with `GridViewColumns` before so this is new.

Also the object I am trying to bind the `ListView` that has the images is something like this:

```
class Film
{
    Image Image {get;set;}
}
```

But if I should store them in a different type other than `Image`, that's cool too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty example that gives an effect similar to what you want:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfListViewDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfListViewDemo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Films}"
                  Background="Black">

            <!-- Panel that will contains the items -->
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                               ItemWidth="150" ItemHeight="220"
                               Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <!-- Template for each item -->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:Film}">
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- Halo that will be shown when the mouse is over the image -->
                        <Ellipse Name="mouseOverHalo" Visibility="Hidden"
                                 Width="180" Height="250"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 ClipToBounds="False">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5, 0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Blue" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="Blue" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Black" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <Image Name="img"
                               Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                               ToolTip="{Binding Title}"
                               Margin="10" />
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- Trigger to display the halo when the mouse is over the image -->
                        <Trigger SourceName="img" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="mouseOverHalo"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible">
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Film class**

```
public class Film
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

**Code-behind**

(You could also use a ViewModel class as the DataContext, I used code-behind here for the sake of simplicity)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Films = new ObservableCollection<Film>(LoadFilms());
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Film> LoadFilms()
    {
        string imagesDirectory = @"D:\Docs\DVD\covers";
        return
            from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(imagesDirectory)
            select new Film
                {
                    Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                    ImagePath = file
                };

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Film> Films { get; private set; }
}
```

The halo is quite ugly right now, but hey, I'm not a designer ;)

Comment: Thanks man, it's really awesome. This will help me learn alot. 2 questions though: 1. Why do I see people using Directory.EnumerateFiles in WPF applications instead of Directory.GetFiles? Is it better? 2. For the halo, I think yours is functional like I wanted but how would I go about making it like the original pic? What I mean is, is this not possible through glow effect? Should I be using some image overlay or something? Thanks again.

Comment: Also Thomas, another thing I have noticed is the images aren't stretched to fit the fixed size for all ListViewItems. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: 1. I prefer to use EnumerateFiles rather than GetFiles because it fetches the file names lazily (GetFiles does it eagerly); admittedly it doesn't really make a difference in that case...

Comment: 2. There's no out-of-the-box glow effect. There *was* an OuterGlowBitmapEffect, but it's deprecated and doesn't work anymore in 4.0. You could use a DropShadowEffect with a ShadowDepth of 0 to simulate the glow effect, but it's not quite the same... The glow in your example is quite large, I'm not sure you could achieve it with just the DropShadowEffect. Have a look at this project if you want more effects: http://wpffx.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can set the Stretch property to Fill on the images, but they will be distorted unless they have the correct aspect ratio...

Comment: Thanks Thomas, sorry wasn't on SO yesterday. I will try it today, but also wondering what algorithm does the Fill Stretching use? Anti-Aliasing or not, etc? Can I specify that too? My covers are very close to the target size so they would be scaled a little but nothing noticeable negatively.

Comment: You can use the [RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode.aspx) attached property to specify the scaling mode to use. You can also have a look at the other properties in this class, I'm not an expect in this field so I don't know exactly what they do...

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is all I needed to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an `ItemsControl`.

As `ItemsPanel` I would use a `WrapPanel`. As `ItemTemplate` you can provide a DataTemplate binding to the Image of your Film, better provide the Image as `ImageSource`, then you can use it straight away as source for an Image element.

Define a Style for your Image in which you define a Trigger for the `IsMouseOver` = true that every FrameworkElement has, whatever eye-candy you want when the mouse is over the image.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, was busy mocking up an example :)  I'll post it anyway:  I added a drop shadow but you can easily change it to a glow., and the C# part just populates a list of file names from a folder next to the .exe.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="pic_viewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pic_viewer"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="item_template" DataType="Item">
        <Image Source="{Binding}"  Width="64" Height="64"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="3" Color="Black"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="pic_list" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Pic}" MethodName="get_pics"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="item_listbox"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource pic_list}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource item_template}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace pic_viewer
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class Pic
    {
        public List<string> get_pics()
        {            
            List<string> p = new List<string>();
            p.Add(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/black.png");
            p.Add(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/blu.png");
            p.Add(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/empty.png");
            p.Add(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/red.png");
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried it now but got this error: "Error 1 'Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: Window. Line 29, position 16.' XML is not valid." Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, the final </Window> was missing.  I've edited it in now.